# Orchard CMS: Custom Taxonomy View Template not working

Tags: taxonomy, orchardcms, custom-view, mvc-editor-templates

I'm using a taxonomy part in one of my custom content types, and using the shape tracer, I was able to create a custom view template for that control (Fields.Contrib.TaxonomyField.cshtml).

When I shape trace the element on the page, under template it indeed shows my custom template exactly as I have it on the external file:

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;

@{
    var terms = (IEnumerable<Contrib.Taxonomies.Models.TermPart>)Model.Terms;
    string name = @Model.ContentField.Name;
}

@if (Model.Terms.Count > 0) {

    @(new HtmlString( string.Join(", ", terms.Select(t => Html.ItemDisplayLink(Html.Encode(t.Name), t.ContentItem ).ToString()).ToArray()) ))
}
<div>TEST TEXT</div>
```

However, when I tab over to the actual outputted HTML, it is showing the standard, built in template, and isn't using my customizations.

```
<p class="taxonomy-field">
    <a href="/categories/coffee-shop">Coffee Shop</a>
</p>
```

According to the shape tracer, it is using my custom template:

> Shape Fields_Contrib_TaxonomyField
>
> **Active Template
>   ~/Themes/Continuum/Views/Fields.Contrib.TaxonomyField.cshtml**
>
> Display Type Detail

this feels like a bug... everything looks like it's wired up correctly... is there something else I need to do to use my custom view template for taxonomy?

Many thanks!

Comment: What specific version of changeset number of the mmodule are you using ?

Comment: I did not realize this was a module, I assumed it was a core part of Orchard. That is unexpected. But anyway, according to the module info it's version 0.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Turns out there was another template created (likely by accident) which was url-specific:

Fields.Contrib.TaxonomyField-url-venues.cshtml

that's the url I was on, and this had the default template still in it. After deleting it, it finally used my custom template.

User error, sorry!!